# _DEBUG and LLVM 5.0 C++ : Preprocessor Expected value in expression

Tags: c++, xcode, compiler-errors, c-preprocessor, llvm

I'm having issues with XCode, LLVM and the `_DEBUG` definition. Or more specifically it seems to be something with underscore.

This is the second time I'm getting an error like this. This time Im compiling against PhysX lib.

> /Library/Frameworks/PhysX.framework/Versions/3.2.1/include/foundation/PxPreprocessor.h:316:35:
>   Expected value in expression

The line it's complaining about:

```
#if !defined(PX_CHECKED) && _DEBUG
```

And it points at right after the _DEBUG. If I remove the underscore it compiles fine (I did that on a similiar library last time as well, see http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=78990). But now Im feeling uneasy about this error. What is causing it and what does it mean?

Settings:
Dialect: C++11, libc++ (Tried different ones, like GNUC++11
Max OSX 10.8
XCode 5
LLVM 5.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Names that begin with an underscore are reserved for the implementation. Instead, use names that don't begin with an underscore unless you are specifically trying to access some implementation-specific feature.

Use defined() on implementation specific macros:

```
#if !defined(PX_CHECKED) && defined(_DEBUG)
```

If there's some reason you are expecting this to work, you haven't explained what it is. There is no reason this should work. What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: I'm using PhysX - It's the PhysX library that are using the _DEBUG macro. They require me to define either _DEBUG or NDEBUG in the compiler but it still won't work. Strange that they are using it ..

Comment: Oh! Then you want `#if !defined(PX_CHECKED) && defined(_DEBUG)`